# Issues with Ubuntu Network Setup

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, cidr

[image: image of Ubuntu network settings]

Please, someone tell me whats up here, I am going bonkers, I have used multiple calculators etc, everything tells me the details in the image are correct but ubuntu just will not accept.

Comment: What information did Hetzner give you?

Comment: You can't have a host 230 in a subnet 255.255.255.240/28

Answer (score 2):

The cause of your confusion is that you mixed up the terms *subnet* and *netmask*.

So if you have been given a `148.251.119.230/28` address by your provider (which is equivalent to a `255.255.255.240` netmask) you should fill the subnet field with `148.251.119.224/28`.

Answer (score 0):

The subnet should be set to 148.251.119.230/28 in your case I think. What you have set is a combination of a netmask and CIDR notation which doesn't work.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073244/set-static-ip-on-ubuntu-core for a previous answer.

Comment: Is that a subnet or an ip address divided by 28?